# How can make a program typing with c++?

Tags: c++

How can make a program typing with c++?

For example with (char) can type a grapheme but i want type word.

```
char x;
x=='c';
```

But i want type for example 'equation'.
Someone know how can i do this?

Comment: With a string. The code you showed is also incorrect.

Comment: What is a "typing" program? You mean something like a text-editor? You can check out the [source code of notepad++](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus) as a popular text-editor written in C++.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `std::string`. You can also use `char*` but i recommend you the first one. Remember that `string` goes within "" instead of ''.

```
string x; //You have to define what is 'x'.
x=="equation";
```

If you use `char*`, it behaves as an array of `char`s.

Comment: i test it,but it did ot work.this is part of my code:(char pro;....  std::cout << "Enter type of process(calculator>c/Volume>v/space>s/Equation>e):";
  std::cin >> pro;...else if (pro == "e") ....)i want instead of 'e' type 'equation'

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <string> // paste this line on top of the file
 
std::string name = "Bob"; // Use double quotes here.

if(name == "Bob")
{
    std::cout << name << std::endl; // works as you expected
}
```